# Passing arguments in Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

As apart of a larger task, I am trying to create a MySQL stored procedure that creates a table. I would like to pass the table's name in the procedure call.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_TABLE(IN tableName VARCHAR(100))
    SET @table_name = tableName;
    SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meta_', @table_name, '(`created` DATETIME, `modified` DATETIME, `enabled` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1);');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

and then there is the call:

```
CALL SP_CREATE_TABLE('data');
```

The procedure works if I hard code `@table_name, but refuses to take the passed parameters.

I am on MySQL 6. Any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CREATE_TABLE(IN tableName VARCHAR(100))
 BEGIN
  SET @table_name = tableName;
  SET @query = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meta_', @table_name, '(`created` DATETIME, `modified` DATETIME, `enabled` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 1);');
  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
 END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you! While trying to get this to work, I had both the BEGIN/END Statements, and Delimiters, but I must have had typos then. Could you possible explain to me why you have `DELIMETER` twice? Other pages Just had the `$$` or in my case a `|`.

Comment: Sure. We are using the first delimiter $$ so the entire SP gets processed as a unit, and doesn't stop at the first ';', and the unit will end at the $$. We are doing the DELIMITER ; at the end to set the delimiter back to default.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, sometimes it is the most obvious things that need and explanation...